# Nested Attributes not saving inside a form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, formtastic

I have Tours, which has_many Photos... Photos belong_to Tours... This is all going okay, but when I try to edit the attributes of an uploaded photo, it will not save in the database... ( I have imported some data, and this saves fine, but it just won't save any changes)

I have a form with nested_attributes

```
= semantic_form_for ([:admin, @tour]), :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
... 
 - @tour.photos.each do |photo|
 ...
 = f.semantic_fields_for photo do |p|
    ...  
    = p.inputs :alt, :description, :temp_src, :remote_image_url
```

The fields populate correctly, but when I save the form.. they do not update...

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

The Tour model simply needed attr_accessible :photo_attributes